# How to freeze rows in datagrid in wpf

Tags: wpftoolkit

I am developing a wpf application which has the wpf grid. I have used the GridSplitter to split the grid columns; if I change the grid column size using the splitter i need to resize the controls in the wiondow based on the column width. Is there any way to identiy the grid splitter moving (I could not find a event in grid splitter for its moving)?

Answer (score 0):

However it seems a bit complicated, you can put a grid in each columns of your grid and then you can use Grid.SizeChanged event.